# Comparison between the Lebesgue integral of a given function over two different sets.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Amid one of my studies, I came across a slight problem. I believe this should be a trivial question for someone that has a strong background in Lebesgue integral theory.

Here it goes:

Let's say we have a certain Lebesgue-integrable function $f$ and two sets $A$ and $B$ such that

$$ f|_A \leqslant f|_B $$

Is it true that

$$ \int_A f(x) dx \leqslant \int_B f(x) dx ? $$

**Note.** I am not sure if the notation is clear, since this question was made up by myself. When I state $f|_A \leqslant f|_B$ I mean that for every $x \in A$ and for every $y \in B$ we have that $f(x) \leqslant f(y).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not true. You would additionally need that $m(A) \leq m(B)$. For a counterexample, consider $f \equiv 1$ and $A=[0,1]$, $B=\{2\}$.

**Edit:** with the additional assumption, we can prove the claim as follows. Let $L = \sup_A f$ and $M = \inf_B f$; your "$f|_A \leq f|_B$" hypothesis states that $L \leq M$. Then
$$
\int_A f \leq L \cdot m(A) \leq M \cdot m(B) \leq \int_B f.
$$

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. This is a bit of over-extending the question I originally asked, but do you think this same condition of $m(A) \leqslant m(B)$ would still be needed if we have knowledge  that $f$ is not a constant a.e. ?

Comment: Absolutely. Take any nonnegative $f$ which is not a.e. zero on $[0,1]$, and the counter-example still works.

Comment: Do you know where I can find a proof of such claim?

Comment: @xyz Assuming non-negativity (as one should, since you can split into positive and negative parts), by your hypotheses we have $\sup_A f \le \inf_B f$ so $\int_A f \le \int_A \sup_A f = (\sup_A f)\mu(A) \le (\inf_B f)\mu(B) = \int_B \inf_B f \le \int_B f$

Comment: @xyz See my edit.